# Quantitative lifting for mod-p elliptic curves to characteristic zero CM elliptic curves

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, iwasawa-theory

Let $A$ be a supersingular elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathcal{O}$ an order in an imaginary quadratic field contained in the quaternion algebra $\operatorname{End}(A)$, then by Deuring's lifting lemma, $A$ lifts to an elliptic curve $E$ over $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ with complex multiplication by an order $\mathcal{O}'$ containing $\mathcal{O}$. For a reference, see "supersingular j-invariants as singular moduli mod-p" by  M. Kaneko. My question is about whether this sort of assertion about lifting can be made quantitative in the following sense.

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the set of all imaginary quadratic fields $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-D})$, and $\mathcal{S}_A$ the subset of $\mathcal{S}$ consisting of all imaginary quadratic fields $K$ such that there exists an elliptic curve $E$ over $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ with complex multiplication by $\mathcal{O}_K$ such that $E$ is a lift of $A$. Given a real number $x>0$, set $\mathcal{S}(x)$ to consist of $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-D})$ such that $D$ is positive, squarefree and $D\leq x$; set $\mathcal{S}_A(x):=\mathcal{S}_A\cap \mathcal{S}(x)$. The sets $\mathcal{S}(x)$ and $\mathcal{S}_A(x)$ are finite, set $\#\mathcal{S}(x)$ (resp. $\#\mathcal{S}_A(x)$) to denote the cardinality of $\mathcal{S}(x)$ (resp. $\mathcal{S}_A(x)$). Then, what can be said about the relative upper density $\limsup_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\#\mathcal{S}_A(x)}{\#\mathcal{S}(x)}$? Is it positive?

There are only finitely many elliptic curves $A$ over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, perhaps these densities are the same for all such $A$. This would be some sort of statement about the equi-distibution of CM j invariants with respect to mod-$p$ reduction. Working explicitly with quarterion algebras (as is done in loc. cit.), it seems to be difficult to derive such a statement. However, perhaps there are tools from arithmetic geometry to prove such a statement? In fact, I'm looking for asymptotic lower bounds for $\#\mathcal{S}_A(x)$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$. I'm hoping to do better than simply show that the set $\mathcal{S}_A$ is infinite.

The reason why I'm interested in this sort of statement has to do with the average behavior of the classical Iwasawa $\lambda$-invariant of an imaginary quadratic field. A recent preprint by M. Stokes https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.09594 establishes the connection between the $\lambda$-invariant of the cyclotomic $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extension of an imaginary quadratic field $K$ in which $p$ splits, and the number of points on the mod-$p$ reduction of any CM elliptic curve $E$ with complex multiplication by $\mathcal{O}_K$.

EDIT: Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the set of all imaginary quadratic fields $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-D})$ such that $p$ is inert in $K$. The set $\mathcal{S}(x)$ consists of $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-D})$ in $\mathcal{S}$ such that $D$ is positive squarefree and $D\leq x$. This seems to be setting in which this question is nontrivial, although it doesn't quite square with the context in which Stokes' result is proven.

Comment: This doesn't exactly imply that the upper density is positive when $p\geq 5$, or does it?

Comment: Writing $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-D})$, the prime $p$ does not split in $K$ if and only if $\left( \tfrac{-D}{p} \right) = -1$. This happens for half of all discriminants $D$ by Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions. For each such $K$, the curves with CM by $\mathcal{O}_K$ are supersingular at $p$. I think that, combined with user491858's comment that all supersingular curves appear when any of them do, this means that the limit of your fraction is $\tfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer The paper I cited mentions a result of Elkies, which would be vacuously true if $\mathcal{S}_A$ contained all such $D$. In fact the paper goes into some detail in finding a $D$ with $D\leq 4/\sqrt{3} \sqrt{p}$. So something about the assertion following user491858's comment doesn't quite add up. In any case, I am actually interested in this question for all $A$, without the supersingular hypothesis and also the family of imaginary quadratic fields for which I would like to prove my result are those in which $p$ splits.

Comment: You're right, I am confused. Well, I am sure of the statement that $p$ doesn't split in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-D})$ for $1/2$ of $D$, and I'm pretty sure that this forces the reduction to be supersingular, so my remaining point of confusion is user491858's statement.

Comment: Thinking more directly about the isogeny claim, if $E_1$ has CM by $\mathcal{O}_K$, and $E_2$ is isogenous to $E_1$, then we can only conclude that $E_2$ has CM by an order in $\mathcal{O}_K$. So, even if there are no issues lifting the isogeny from char. $p$ to char. $0$, you'd still need to be careful about exactly what CM ring you get.

Comment: I have no progress on the main question, which I think is very interesting, but I think the non-super singular version doesn't work. If $E$ has CM by $\mathcal{O}_K$, and $p$ is an ordinary prime for $E$, then the $j$-invariant of $E$ should lie in $\mathbb{F}_p$ if and only if $p$ splits principally in $K$. (This is because the $j$ invariant generates $H_K$ over $K$.) For a fixed $p$, there are only finitely many imaginary quadratic fields in which it splits principally.

Comment: @user491858 True, good point.

Comment: @user491858 It seems like this would give lower bounds on class numbers. There are $\approx p/12$ supersingular $j$-invariants and $h_D$ curves with CM by $\mathcal{O}_K$, so $h_D \geq p/12$ once $D$ is large enough for the results on ternary forms to apply. Does this come close to being useful?

Comment: @user491858 Well, only $\approx h_p$ are of them are in $\mathbb{F}_p$, but that should still be big enough to cause a problem.

Comment: Taking a closer look at p. 852 of the paper, it seems that the condition for D is that if it is representable by an integral binary quadratic form in variables x,z then there is an elliptic curve with CM by $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-D})$ which is a lift of the given supersingular elliptic curve. This quadratic form has determinant 4p. So one should be able to prove a lot using results about integers that can be represented by a quadratic form. If one restricts ones attention to prime values of D, then this seems to come down to congruence conditions for D.

Comment: Note that it is only a binary form because the author only wanted a lower bound and  set $y=0$ to make his analysis simpler. If you look at eqn 2-2 on that page, it is a positive ternary form of determinant $4p^2$. So what you need are asymptotics for how many $D$ are representatible by a positive definite ternary form of determinant $4p^2$.

Comment: @user491858 Actually, I think you are on the right track. I computed the endomorphism rings of the two supersingular $j$-invariants modulo $11$, and found many primes which were represented by both ternary forms. The ternary forms in question are $q_0(x,y,z):=3 x^2 + 11 (y^2 + y z + z^2)$ and $q_{1728}(x,y,z)=11 x^2 + (y^2 + y z + 3 z^2)$. If $q_j(x,y,z)=D$, we get an action of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-D}]$ on the curve mod $11$ with $j$-invariant $j$. The condition to extend to $\tfrac{1+\sqrt{-D}}{2}$ is that $(x,y,z) \equiv (1,0,0) \bmod 2$ in each case. (continued)

Comment: There are many primes in both lists, starting 47, 71, 179, 191, 251, 311, 383, 419, 599, 647, 719, 839, 863, 911, 983. How can this be? I computed the minimal polynomial of $j(\tfrac{1+\sqrt{-47}}{2})$. It is $x^5+2257834125 x^4-9987963828125 x^3+5115161850595703125 x^2-14982472850828613281250  x+16042929600623870849609375$. (continued)

Comment: Modulo $11$, that is $(x-0)^2 (x-1728)^3$. Of course, the field generated by the $j$-invariant is not ramified at $11$, but the minimal polynomial of the $j$-invariant is a different story!

Comment: Sorry, $q_0$ isn't maximal at $3$. But a larger order just means more primes.

Comment: @user491858 The setting in which Stokes' result (mentioned in the last para of the question) are the imaginary quadratic fields $K$ in which the prime $p$ splits. Therefore, I really am interested in the family of imaginary quadratic fields in which $p$ splits. Perhaps that should be an added stipulation in the definition of $\mathcal{S}$ and $\mathcal{S}_A$, i.e., $\mathcal{S}$ consists of imaginary quadratic fields in which $p$ splits, and $\mathcal{S}_A$ is the subset of $\mathcal{S}$. In this setting, the lift is defined over $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: @user491858 Here is what is confusing. Let's say that what you say is correct. Then, every elliptic curve $A$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ lifts to either $0$ or $1$ elliptic curve with complex multiplication by an imaginary quadratic field $K$ in which $p$ splits. Therefore, there are only finitely many imaginary quadratic fields $K$ in which $p$ splits   for which an elliptic curve $E$ with CM by $\mathcal{O}_K$ has good reduction at $p$? Indeed there are only finitely many choices of $A$ and hence only finitely many $K$ according to what you say.

Comment: @user491858 That makes a lot of sense. I think I understand what I'm getting wrong here. Is it possible for an elliptic curve $A$ over $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p$ to lift to infinitely many CM elliptic curves $E$ by $K$ in which $p$ splits? There should be no assumption on the field over which $A$ is defined. The issue with this is that there are now infinitely many $A$.

Comment: It seems therefore that this sort of question is only interesting for supersingular $A$ and $K$ in which $p$ is inert. Unfortunately, this doesn't square with what I'm interested in doing and if one is considering $K$ in which $p$ splits one must consider all $A$ defined over $\bar{F}_p$ and it doesn't quite make sense to study it in this way.

Comment: @user491858 Sorry, I've been travelling, I'm going to change the wording, thanks.

Comment: For the record, I factored the quintic above modulo $29$ and got $x (x-25)^2 (x-2)^2$. So it is possible for the lift to require an extension of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ even away from the special moduli of $0$ and $1728$.

Comment: I've been reading up on quaternion algebras in my spare time and I think @user491858 is correct: If we fix $p$ and fix a supersingular $j$-invariant $j_0$ modulo $p$ then, for all sufficiently large $D$ with $\left( \tfrac{-D}{p} \right) = -1$, there should be a $j$-invariant over some extension of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ with CM by the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-D})$ such that $j \equiv j_0 \bmod p$. (I also think this is right if $j_0$ is in $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$, not $\mathbb{F}_p$.) I'm still going to let user491858 do the right up though.

Comment: Here are two variants that I like. Let $J(p)$ be the set of supersingular $j$-invariants in $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ and let $J_0(p)$ be those in $\mathbb{F}_p$. Let $h_D(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $j(\tfrac{1+\sqrt{-D}}{2})$ or $j(\sqrt{-D})$ as appropriate. Question 1: Factor $h_D(x) = \prod_{j \in J(p)} (x-j)^{a_{j,D}}$. What can we say about $\lim_{D \to \infty} a_{j,D}/(\deg h_D)$? Question 2: Restrict to $D$ prime and $3 \bmod 4$. Then $h_D(x)$ has exactly one root $j_D \in \mathbb{Z}_p$. For fixed $j_0 \in J_0(p)$, what can we say about the density of $D$ with $j_D \equiv j_0 \bmod p$?

Comment: @user491858 I'm going to be really busy the whole week since I am in the process of moving to a new place, I will read your answer carefully once I get time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E$ be a supersingular elliptic curve in characteristic $p$. Then
$A = \mathrm{End}(E)$ is a maximal order in the quaternion algebra
$D/\mathbf{Q}$ ramified exactly at $p$ and $\infty$. If $\alpha \in A \smallsetminus  \mathbf{Z}$, then Deuring's theorem guarantees that the pair $(E,\alpha)$ can be lifted to a characteristic zero, and the lift will necessarily be a CM elliptic curve. If $K$ is an imaginary quadratic field then $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathbf{Z}[\alpha]$ for some $\alpha$, so the question as to whether $E$ can be lifted to an elliptic curve with CM by  the full ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ is equivalent to asking that there is an inclusion

$$\mathcal{O}_K \rightarrow A.$$

A necessary condition is that $K \hookrightarrow D$. This is equivalent to the condition that $K$ splits $D$, which is equivalent to the condition that $p$ does not split in $K$. So from now on restrict to such $p$.

Consider for convenience of exposition the case when $K$ has even discriminant so one can choose $\alpha = \sqrt{-\Delta_K}$. Then $\alpha \in A$ if and only if there exists a trace zero element in $A$ with norm $\Delta_K$.  The trace zero elements form a rank three module (over $\mathbf{Z}$), and so the condition that $\Delta_K$ be a norm is equivalent to asking that $\Delta_K$ is represented by the corresponding ternary quadratic form $P_A(x,y,z)$. Understanding what numbers are represented by ternary quadratic forms is a tricky problem in general. In this setting, the ternary quadratic forms $P_A$ depend on $A$. However, these forms are all locally the same for all finite places. So the easy thing to compute is how many ways an integer is represented by $P_A(x,y,z)$ for some $A$. But this is just the number of CM elliptic curves with endomorphisms by
$\mathcal{O}_K$ which is the class number $h_K$. This is why  things are much simpler when there is only one supersingular point which occurs for only finitely many $p$. When $p=2$, for example, then $D$ is the Hamilton quaternions and  $P_A(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$, and the number of ways of representing a prime in this form is directly related to class numbers, as was understood by Gauss. For larger $p$, there will be a similar formula for the number of ways of representing numbers in terms of *some* $P_A$, but understanding the individual factors is more complicated.

In more general settings of ternary definite quadratic forms,
The best one can hope for is that an integer $\Delta_K$ is represented by such a form as long as it is locally representable and $D$ is sufficiently large. (Small $D$ are always going to be difficult.) Even this is too much to ask for general ternary quadratic forms (a good introductory reference is here [https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~cass/siegel/hanke-ternary.pdf](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecass/siegel/hanke-ternary.pdf)).
Fortunately it turns out for this particular case that we are in the best situation, and the conclusion is indeed that, fixing $p$, lifts exist for any $K$ where $p$ does not split as long as $\Delta_K \gg_p 1$. But even more is true. We know there are $h_K \gg D^{1/2 - \varepsilon}$  CM elliptic curves by the ring of integers of $K$. It turns out that there reductions are distributed uniformly among the supersingular points as $\Delta_K \rightarrow \infty$. This follows from Theorem 3 of Michel's paper (https://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v160-n1-p05.pdf)

**Some Variations** There are a number of other variations that could be asked. The question (somewhat artificially) considered supersingular elliptic curves over $\mathbf{F}_p$. One could insist on finding CM lifts which are themselves defined over $\mathbf{Z}_p$. To be precise, since $p$ is inert in $K$, these lifts do not actually have CM over the base field, but they
are lifts over $\mathbf{Z}_p$ which have CM over some extension. For convenience let us also restrict to $K/\mathbf{Q}$ of prime discriminant. Then one can ask:

**Problem:** For a fixed $p$, let $K/\mathbf{Q}$ range over imaginary quadratic fields of prime discriminant. What is the distribution of which supersingular elliptic curves over $\mathbf{F}_p$ lift to a (potentially) CM elliptic curve over $\mathbf{Z}_p$?

To be more specific, we know that when $K$ has prime discriminant then $h_K$ is odd. Let $H_K$ be the class field. The decomposition group at $p$ of $\mathrm{Gal}(H_K/\mathbf{Q})$
surjects onto $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbf{Q})$ because $p$ is inert in this field; since $h_K$ is odd, this implies that the decomposition group in $\mathrm{Gal}(H_K/\mathbf{Q})$ is (any of the) reflections. Since the $j$-invariant of any CM elliptic curve is fixed by exactly one reflection, it follows that there will be a *unique* elliptic curve over $\mathbf{Z}_p$ which has (potential) CM by $\mathcal{O}_K$. The mod-$p$ reduction of this curve then gives  a unique supersingular elliptic curve over $\mathbf{F}_p$ determined by $\Delta_K$. How are these reductions distributed as $\Delta_K$ ranges over all admissible primes?

To make this even more explicit, let $p=11$, so there are two supersingular elliptic curves with $j=0$ and $j = 1728$.
Let $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ be a prime such that $11$ is inert in $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{-p})$, so $p \not\equiv 2,6,7,8,10 \bmod 11$.  There is a class polynomial $P(x)$ of degree $h_K$, and this will have a unique root defined over $\mathbf{Z}_{11}$. For what primes $p$ is this root $0 \bmod 11$ and for what primes is it $1728 \bmod 11$? (This question came up naturally from discussions with David Speyer in the comments). For example, with $\Delta_K = -3, -23, -31, -47$, the reductions are $j = 0,0,0,1728$. The first case is obvious, the modular equations in the next two cases are

$$t^3 + 3491750t^2 - 5151296875t + 12771880859375,$$
$$t^3 + 39491307t^2 - 58682638134t + 1566028350940383,$$

and the last case is computed in the comments). The default guess in this case is presumably that they each occur roughly half the time.

The question of understanding supersingular isogenies is something that seems to be intensively studied for cryptography,
so these questions may well be known.